# Using `paste` inside dplyr::transmute

Tags: r, dplyr

"For which digits `x` and `y` the number whose representation in the Decimal numeral system is `6x12y` is divided by `45` ?"

The following is not of course the solution that discussed with my doughter, but an attempt to test my skills in R. However, the last line doesn't do what I want.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

replicate(2, 0:9, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
  expand.grid() %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  transmute(newcol=do.call(paste0,list(6,Var1,12,Var2))) %>% 
  map_df(as.numeric) %>% 
  filter(newcol%%45==0) %>% 
  transmute(x_y=paste(stri_sub(newcol,c(2,5),c(2,5)),collapse = " "))
```

I got the desired result using this. But what is my mistake in the previous one?

```
replicate(2, 0:9, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
  expand.grid() %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  transmute(newcol=do.call(paste0,list(6,Var1,12,Var2))) %>% 
  map_df(as.numeric) %>% 
  filter(newcol%%45==0) %>% 
  transmute(x_y=map2_chr(stri_sub(newcol,2,2),stri_sub(newcol,5,5),paste))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to your operation rowwise. Thus, adding the `rowwise()` condition in your pipe will fix it, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

replicate(2, 0:9, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
    expand.grid() %>% 
    as.tibble() %>% 
    transmute(newcol=do.call(paste0,list(6,Var1,12,Var2))) %>% 
    map_df(as.numeric) %>% 
    filter(newcol%%45==0) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% # <--- Added the rowwise
    transmute(x_y=paste(stri_sub(newcol,c(2,5),c(2,5)),collapse = " "))
```

Which gives the expected result,

> ```
> Source: local data frame [3 x 1]
> Groups: <by row>
>
> # A tibble: 3 x 1
>     x_y
>   <chr>
> 1   0 0
> 2   9 0
> 3   4 5
> ```